# Bacteria population growth confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In one of my course, it is said that a bacteria population growth can be modelled by the differential equation $P(t)'=rP(t)$ where $r$ is the growth rate. The solution of the above equation is $P_{0} e^{rt}$ which bugs me quite a lot. I looked up the Internet and found this [article](https://betterexplained.com/articles/an-intuitive-guide-to-exponential-functions-e/) which explains that bacteria growth is characterised by the function $P_{0} 2^t$. Can someone help me to clear this up?

Comment: My problem with this reasoning is that r is supposed is suppose to represent a growth rate of 100% as in the article. How do you know in advance that r in the differential equation will be different? This DE is derived in the course from the fact that $P(t+\Delta t) - P(t) = rP(t)\Delta t$ which is a priori found by simple book-keeping. Intuitively for me, this r of 100% should lead to a function such as $2^t$ and not $e^t$. That is what bugs me.

Comment: That web page is wrong about the bacteria. You do not start at time $0$ with a bunch of "Mr. Blue" bacteria of which every one is about to start spawning a new "Mr. Green." An actual colony of bacteria has bacteria in every stage of reproduction at any given time, so you are (almost) continuously getting new bacteria. It actually works more like the compound-interest-on-money example that is shown after the bacteria.

Comment: @DavidK But isn't it true that a not completely born/formed bacteria cannot start to divide into two bacterial?

Comment: It's also important to realise that these equations are only simple models of what is happening and won't necessarily be exact in the real world. Also note that having $r$ as an unknown still includes the possibility that $r$ relates to 100%, but it also includes the possibility that it has another value.

Comment: @Dory it is not the incompletely formed bacteria that divide. My point is that if the bacteria divide once every 60 seconds, then at any instant that you look at the colony there will be some bacteria that last divided 59 seconds ago and have just 1 second left before they finish dividing again, some that divided 58 seconds, ago, and so forth. By the way, there will be almost twice as many that divided 1 second ago as the number that divided 59 seconds ago.

Comment: @DavidK Ok I think I'm starting to see your point but I'm still not really sure about what that implies. I feel like even if every bacteria are going to divide themselves at different times, still after one minute every bactery has divided itself once so you should get twice as much bacteria than the in the previous minute but that seems to better correspond to the function $2^t$ than $e^2t$. Maybe you could provide an example? :)

Comment: You can certainly have growth according to $2^t$--provided that $P'(t) = (\ln 2)P(t)$. That is, if $r = \ln 2$ in the equation in your question, then you get growth at $e^{rt} = e^{(\ln 2) t} = 2^t$. The formula $e^{2t}$ would come from a much faster-growing population. Among other issues, I think you are getting $r$ confused with $1+r$.

Comment: Maybe this explains it better: http://www.mpi-bremen.de/Binaries/Binary13037/Wachstumsversuch.pdf